# ISet<T> that notifies on add and remove?

Tags: c#

I'd like an `ISet<T>` with two additional events `ItemAdded` and `ItemRemoved`.

One option I considered was deriving `MyHashSet<T>` from `HashSet<T>` but since `Add` and `Remove` are not virtual, it would require the use of `new`.  Maybe this is a valid use of the keyword?

Another option I thought would be to implement `ISet<T>` and delegate everything to a private instance of `HashSet<T>`.  This feels like a bulky solution.

Is there a pattern or framework class that gets me the same result but doesn't require less than elegant/ideal coding?

Comment: You can keep a private instance of a `HashSet` in your class instead of inheriting from `HashSet`. The implementation should be straightforward then.

Comment: Your option to implement `ISet<T>` is a good one, this correlates with the suggestion of favoring composition over inheritance.

Comment: Agreed.  I think implementing ISet with a priveate HashSet would be easiest.

Comment: I've used `new` keyword in such case, haven't had any complaints :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your own answer demonstrates how you can wrap a `HashSet<T>` and Srikanth's answer demonstrates how you can derive from `HashSet<T>`. However, when you derive from `HashSet<T>` you have to make sure the new class also correctly implements the `Add` and `Remove` methods of the `ICollection<T>` interface. So I have modified Srikanth's answer to properly create an `ISet<T>` implementation with notifications that derives from `HashSet<T>` by using explicit interface implementation of the relevant methods of `ICollection<T>`:

```
public class NotifyingHashSet<T> : HashSet<T>, ICollection<T> {

  new public void Add(T item) {
    ((ICollection<T>) this).Add(item);
  }

  new public Boolean Remove(T item) {
    return ((ICollection<T>) this).Remove(item);
  }

  void ICollection<T>.Add(T item) {
    var added = base.Add(item);
    if (added)
      OnItemAdded(new NotifyHashSetEventArgs<T>(item));
  }

  Boolean ICollection<T>.Remove(T item) {
    var removed = base.Remove(item);
    if (removed)
      OnItemRemoved(new NotifyHashSetEventArgs<T>(item));
    return removed;
  }

  public event EventHandler<NotifyHashSetEventArgs<T>> ItemAdded;

  public event EventHandler<NotifyHashSetEventArgs<T>> ItemRemoved;

  protected virtual void OnItemRemoved(NotifyHashSetEventArgs<T> e) {
    var handler = ItemRemoved;
    if (handler != null)
      ItemRemoved(this, e);
  }

  protected virtual void OnItemAdded(NotifyHashSetEventArgs<T> e) {
    var handler = ItemAdded;
    if (handler != null)
      ItemAdded(this, e);
  }

}

public class NotifyHashSetEventArgs<T> : EventArgs {

  public NotifyHashSetEventArgs(T item) {
    Item = item;
  }

  public T Item { get; private set; }

}
```

This class also behaves the same way as your class by only firing events when an element actually is added or removed from the set. E.g., adding the same element twice in succession will only fire one event.

Comment: considering all the options, and the fact that the very next thing I had to do with my answer/solution was expose the internal hashset so I could sort it, I decided this was the best of all worlds.  I know I have to deal with the fact that the events won't fire if it is up-casted, but I can't think of a case where I'd pass it off like that where the set would be mutated as a result

Comment: This won't work if the type is casted to `HashSet<T>`.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the comments I received (thanks) here's what I've got:

```
public class NotifyingHashSet<T>
{
    private HashSet<T> hashSet = new HashSet<T>();

    public bool Add(T item)
    {
        bool added = hashSet.Add(item);
        if(added && ItemAdded != null)
        {
            ItemAdded(this, new NotifyingHashSetEvent<T>(item));
        }
        return added;
    }

    public bool Remove(T item)
    {
        bool removed = hashSet.Remove(item);
        if(removed && ItemRemoved != null)
        {
            ItemRemoved(this, new NotifyingHashSetEvent<T>(item));
        }
        return removed;
    }

    public event EventHandler<NotifyingHashSetEvent<T>> ItemAdded;

    public event EventHandler<NotifyingHashSetEvent<T>> ItemRemoved;
}

public class NotifyingHashSetEvent<T> : EventArgs
{
    public NotifyingHashSetEvent(T item)
    {
        Item = item;
    }

    public T Item { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This must solve your problem but `NotifyingHashSet<T>` does not implement `ISet<T>` which was what you wanted in your question. Obviously, doing that would not by very hard because most of the methods can simply be forwarded to the `HashSet<T>` instance. I guess this can be left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: I know - i took the comments I got to imply my best option was this.. I guess I was hoping for some "magic" that I didn't know about but sometimes you just have to type it up!

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend `inheriting` rather than `composing` in this case.

This will ensure that you get all that HashSet offers like:

- Other collection methods such as `Contains` and other Set operations such as `IsSubsetOf`
- Collection initializers
- You could assign it to base type, `HashSet<int> foo = new NotifyingHashSet<int>()`

My implementation looks like this:

```
public class NotifyingHashSet<T> : HashSet<T>
{

    public new void Add(T item)
    {
        OnItemAdded(new NotifyHashSetChanged<T>(item));
        base.Add(item);
    }
    public new void Remove(T item)
    {
        OnItemRemoved(new NotifyHashSetChanged<T>(item));
        base.Remove(item);
    }

    public event EventHandler<NotifyHashSetChanged<T>> ItemAdded;
    public event EventHandler<NotifyHashSetChanged<T>> ItemRemoved;

    protected virtual void OnItemRemoved(NotifyHashSetChanged<T> e)
    {
        if (ItemRemoved != null) ItemRemoved(this, e);
    }

    protected virtual void OnItemAdded(NotifyHashSetChanged<T> e)
    {
        if (ItemAdded != null) ItemAdded(this, e);
    }
}

public class NotifyHashSetChanged<T> : EventArgs
{
    private readonly T _item;

    public NotifyHashSetChanged(T item)
    {
        _item = item;
    }

    public T ChangedItem
    {
        get { return _item; }
    }
}
```

Some tests to check stuff:

```
[TestClass]
public class NotifyingHashSetTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void ShouldAddToNotifyingHashSet()
    {
        var notifyingHashSet = new NotifyingHashSet<int>();
        notifyingHashSet.ItemAdded += (sender, changed) => Assert.AreEqual(changed.ChangedItem, 1);
        notifyingHashSet.Add(1);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void ShouldRemoveFromNotifyingHashSet()
    {
        //can use collection initializer
        var notifyingHashSet = new NotifyingHashSet<int> { 1 };
        notifyingHashSet.ItemRemoved += (sender, changed) => Assert.AreEqual(changed.ChangedItem, 1);
        notifyingHashSet.Remove(1);
    }        

    [TestMethod]
    public void ShouldContainValueInNotifyingHashSet()
    {
        //can use collection initializer
        var notifyingHashSet = new NotifyingHashSet<int> { 1 };
        Assert.IsTrue(notifyingHashSet.Contains(1));
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void ShouldAssignToHashSet()
    {
        HashSet<int> notifyingHashSet = new NotifyingHashSet<int> { 1 };
        Assert.IsTrue(notifyingHashSet.IsSubsetOf(new List<int>{ 1,2 }));
    }
}
```

Comment: Simply hiding `Add` and `Remove` will not always work. If `NotifyingHashSet<T>` is cast `ISet<T>` or `ICollection<T>` (which it will be if it is used as a parameter to a function accepting one of these interfaces) the `HashSet<T>` and not the `NotifyingHashSet<T>` implementation will be called and no event is fired. You can fix this by deriving `NotifyingHashSet<T>` from `ICollection<T>` and providing explicit interface implementations of the `ICollection<T>.Add` and `ICollection<T>.Remove` methods that fire events.

Comment: You're right, but that's the problem I faced when I tried to pass a `List<T>` too. `IEnumerable<T>` does not have `List<T>` methods specified. And the workaround would be to call a `ToList` and then perform `List` specific operations.

Comment: The other option that comes to mind is to have an extension method `AddWithNotification` to `HashSet<T>` ? Strike that, one cannot add extensions to generic types.